# Why the output is coming like this?

Tags: c, calculator, division, integer-division

When I tried to do division of 6/3 the output comes like this 2 / -1431650288. What's wrong in code?
My program in c is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char Operator;
    int num1, num2;

    printf("Enter the operator in which you want to perform calculation(+, -, *, /)\n");
    scanf(" %c", &Operator);

    if (Operator == '/'){
        printf("Enter two numbers: ");
    scanf(" %d %d", &num1, &num2);
     if (num2==0){
            printf("\a Denominator must be greater than 0.\n");
        }
        else{
            printf(" %d / %d", num1/num2);
        }
    } 
    else{
    printf("Enter two integer numbers: ");
    scanf(" %d %d", &num1, &num2);

    if(Operator =='+'){
        printf(" %d + %d = %d", num1, num2, num1+num2);
    }
    else if(Operator == '-'){
      printf(" %d - %d = %d", num1, num2, num1-num2);
    }
    else if(Operator == '*'){
      printf(" %d * %d = %d", num1, num2, num1*num2);
    }

    else{
       printf("\t \a Invalid Operator.\n");
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please ask a clear question. *What's wrong in my code* is not an actual, valid question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: What is the exact input you give your program? What is the exact (copy-pasted) output? What is the *expected* output?

Comment: Also, have you tried [to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes I tried. As being a new user stackoverflow doesn't allow me to upload picture that's why I can't show you output.

Comment: The output is text, copy-paste it as text. Don't post images or text, please.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry and thanks. I got answer.

Comment: Listen to your compiler, enable warnings! `prog.cc:18:28: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
            printf(" %d / %d", num1/num2);`

Comment: @hellow thank you. I got answer.

Comment: I know, but I want you to help to not ask such questions in the future, but instead solve them on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
printf(" %d / %d", num1/num2);
```

The first '%d' is the result of num1/num2 and that's enough. The second %d and the '/' character should not be here. Change it to:

```
printf(" %d ", num1/num2);
```

Additionaly, for your purpose, the switch case structure is more suitable for code readability (and better optimization too I think)